# PostgreSQL statement to extract previous date data

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a cronjob that looks at load previous day data sourcing another table that gets refreshed on a daily basis. I am looking to update the job to source from origination table that holds entire year of data. However I am just looking to capture and load previous 1 day of data from the origination table. The origination table has a date updated field which is in timestamptz format (ex - 2022-08-01 20:20:20.736+00). Any recommendation on what function to place where the job picks up:
last_updated from >= 2022-08-01 10:00:00 and last_updated from <= 2022-08-02 10:00:00. Assuming I am running this on 2022-08-02 11:00:00.

Thanks,

Comment: `...WHERE last_updated BETWEEN '2022-08-01 10:00:00'::timestamptz AND '2022-08-02 10:00:00'::timestamptz...`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the response. The challenge here is I want to automate the date as such when the cronjob run the following day i.e. 2022-08-03 the date gets auto updated to say ".WHERE last_updated BETWEEN '2022-08-02 10:00:00'::timestamptz AND '2022-08-03 10:00:00'::timestamptz".

Comment: If you have access to the other table, I recommend something like `select * from source_table where last_updated > (select max(last_updated) from other_table);`

Comment: the other table where I believe you are referring to holds the daily data. No, that will not work as it resides in another database.

Comment: `...WHERE last_updated BETWEEN (current_date - '1 day'::interval  + '10:00'::time)::timestamptz AND (current_date + '10:00'::time)::timestamptz...`

Comment: Are you running the query at 10:00:00 clock or the time is dynamic at the runtime

Comment: Hi Sunder the job the scheduled to run at 11am every day. There is a flexibility on when to run the job. However I am capturing the data as of 10.00 clock.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for the feedback. I will try it and response accordingly.